# Using huggingface transformers with a non English language

Tags: python-3.x, multilingual, huggingface-transformers

I have installed the latest version of transformers and I was able to use its simple syntax to make sentiment prediction of English phrases:

```
from transformers import pipeline
sentimentAnalysis = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
print(sentimentAnalysis("Transformers piplines are easy to use"))
HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0, description='Downloading', max=442.0, style=ProgressStyle(description_…

HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0, description='Downloading', max=629.0, style=ProgressStyle(description_…

HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0, description='Downloading', max=230.0, style=ProgressStyle(description_…

HBox(children=(FloatProgress(value=0.0, description='Downloading', max=267844284.0, style=ProgressStyle(descri…

[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9305251240730286}]

print(sentimentAnalysis("Transformers piplines are extremely easy to use"))

[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.9820092916488647}]
```

However, when I tried it on a non-English language (here is Greek) I did not get the results I expected.

The following phrase translates in English as: `'This food is disgusting'` and I would expect I very low sentiment score which is not what I got:

```
print(sentimentAnalysis("Αυτό το φαγητό είναι αηδιαστικό"))
[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.7899578213691711}]
```

Here is an attempt to use the best multilingual model:

[image]

Somewhat better but still widely out of target.

Is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `pipelines` by default load an English model. In the case of sentiment analysis, this is `distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english`, see [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/pipelines.py#L1581).

Fortunately, you can just specify the exact model that you want to load, as described in the [docs for `pipeline`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html#transformers.pipeline):

```py
from transformers import pipeline
pipe = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model="<your_model_here>", tokenizer="<your_tokenizer_here>")
```

Keep in mind that these need to be models compatible with the architecture of your respective task. The only greek model I could find was `nlpaueb/bert-base-greek-uncased-v1`, which seems like a base model to me. In that case, you'd first need to fine-tune your own model for sentiment analysis, and then could load from that checkpoint. Otherwise, you might get questionable results as well.

Comment: Tokenizers for pipelines can be determined in a similar fashion, check which one is loaded for each respective model. Generally, it is similar to the one that you would use in the bert-base-multilingual model as well. As for any further questions, please consider opening a new question instead of updating an old one.